# Laravel talk doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

I installed laravel talk package, added my app pusher keys to env and my chat is not live.. Do you know what to do? That app is on localhost.

I did everything what author said in github page.

Comment: Please be more specific, what do you mean it "is not live"? are there any logs or error messages you can share? what other settings have you applied?

Comment: nothing. When I write queue command id doesn't work. Nothing happens